# Is rsync the best way to keep four drives synched?

Tags: rsync, backup, synchronization

I googled but I can't see the best solution for my purpose.
Using LUKS I have physical drives: A,B,C,D

I need:

- when I write something on drive A, automatically or scheduled changes are written on drive B and D
- When I write on drive B, changes are written on drive A and D
- When I write on drive C, changes are written on drive D.

A: 1 Terabyte
B: 1 Terabyte
C: 1 Terabyte
D: 2 Terabyte

A,B,C,D could be turned on at different times

I need the change of rename or move to be ported, instead of deleting and re-transferring the entire file/folder.

Can rsync be the best way?
Any else solution?
Thanks!

Comment: This would usually sound more like a job for RAID. Are your your drives permanently connected, or removed?

Comment: Can happen drives are not connected at the same time

Comment: look at www.rsnapshot.org.  It uses `rsync`.  It will not *backup* data real time as soon as a something is written to disk.  You schedule `rsnapshot` to run with `cron` and the `rsnapshot.conf` is easy enough to configure to where you can achieve your desired A/B/C/D backup scheme.  Schedule rsnapshot to run however often in cron.

Comment: Depending on whether you want a) just a backup or b) to share changes in files between multiple systems without using a file server, this job might be better suited to [unison](https://github.com/bcpierce00/unison) than `rsync`.   rsync is really only a one-way synchronisation tool, i.e. from a source directory to a target directory.  Try to use it in both directions and you'll run into problems (esp. related to deleted files on the source or the target).   Unison uses an rsync-like algorithm to keep two directory trees in sync, no matter where any additions/changes/deletions were made.

Comment: Are those drives local? For remote synchronization the Syncthing is a good tool. Also note that any synchronization (except RAID) would potentially lead to editing conflicts which you'd have to resolve manually.

Comment: I tried to use a logical raid1 with mdadm but it doesn't work for me, because I need to be able to write individually to a disk and then only copy to a folder on the other disk (I'd prefer to avoid partitions so as not to reduce the size of the 2TB ).
I tried rsync but when I copy data from A to D, I risk losing the data written to B since A and B do not align directly to each other and are used separately.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following setup:

Split D into two partions D1 and D2, where the size of D1 equals A and B, and D2 equals C

Then make two RAID1 systems, one consiting of A, B, D1 and one of C, D2.

`mdadm` allows for this software-based RAID.

Grouping into RAIDs makes syncronization instantanious.

Comment: If D1 is not ready at the moment when I write on disk A, when I connect D1 automatically mdadm syncs to D1?

Comment: yes. Or you can use snapraid for the replication (its designed to work with offline devices / infrequent availability)

Comment: With snapraid I can write on disk A it sync on disk D and then when i write on disk D it writes on disk A?